# Increment list based on number pattern

Tags: python, list

I have a list of zeros and ones that looks like this:

```
lst = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

How can I transform this lst into this:

```
transformed_lst = lst = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 4]
```

Basically, at each occurance of a 1, transform it to an n+1 integer. I'm sure there is an elegant way to do this with itertools/groupby/functools. Here is an attempt, but not quite correct:

```
from itertools import cycle

ints = cycle(range(len(lst))) 
transformed_lst = [next(ints) if i != 0 in lst else 0 for i in lst]  

>>> [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 7, 8]
```

Comment: No, `map` won't do. It applies a function to the list, but here you need some state to remember between calls. This is not nicely handled with a function. A generator function should be well suited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `itertools.count()`,`itertools.chain()` and `itertools.groupby()`:

```
In [14]: from itertools import *

In [15]: c=count(1)

In [16]: lis=[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]

In [17]: list(chain(*[list(g) if k!=1 else [next(c)]*len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(lis)]))

Out[17]: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 4]
```

here you can also use `sum(1 for _ in g)` in place of `len(list(g))`

As Demanded, a readable version using generator function:

```
In [27]: def func(l):
    c=count(1)
    for k,g in groupby(l):
        if k==1:
            for x in [next(c)]*sum(1 for _ in g):
                yield x
        else:
            for x in g:
                yield x
   ....:                 

In [28]: list(func(lis))
Out[28]: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Smooth, I was gonna post something far uglier :)

Comment: Zero points for maintainability and such. But its a one-liner :)

Comment: To make it readable just pull it out into separate lines and store the inner spots. Tricky oneliner but not horrible, especially with comments :P

Answer (score 6):

You basically have two states - "reading `0`s" and "reading `1`s" -  and when you switch between then (namely from ones to zeroes) the delta to be applied for subsequent `1`s change:

```
reading_zeroes = True
delta = 0
for x in input:
    if x:
        reading_zeroes = False
        x += delta
    elif not reading_zeroes:
        delta += 1
        reading_zeroes = True
    yield x
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that you only have a "next group" when the current element is 1 and the previous element is 0.

```
previous = 0
grp = 0
for elem in lst:
    if elem and not previous:
         grp += 1
    previous = elem
    yield (grp if elem else 0)
```

Comment: I like this one.  You could even make it shorter:  `grp += bool( elem and not previous )` -- Though that's probably not better :).  And in the same vein, you could do `yeild grp*bool(elem)`, but again, probably not better.

Comment: @mgilson: I was considering `grp * bool(elem)`, but yeah.  Wasn't exactly self documenting.  Didn't want to get *too* tricky, considering i don't know Python.  :)

Comment: With this limited case (`1`s and `0`s) you don't even need `bool` -- `grp*elem` would work fine.  But doing the general case is only sightly more effort :).  Anyway, +1 for a nice solution and taking the high road :^)

Answer (score 2):

```py
>>> lst = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [i//2 if k else 0 for i, (k, g) in enumerate(groupby(lst), 2) for j in g]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lst = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
>>> transformed = []
>>> idx = 1
>>> for key, grp in groupby(lst):
...    if key:
...       transformed += [idx] * len(list(grp))
...       idx += 1
...    else:
...       transformed += list(grp)
... 
>>> transformed
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this to be a good blend between readability and brevity (doesn't need to keep track of states):

```
from itertools import groupby

def transform(numbers):
    counter = 0
    for value, iterator in groupby(numbers):
        if value:
            counter += 1

        for i in iterator:
            if value:
                yield counter
            else:
                yield 0

pre_transformed = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
print list(transform(pre_transformed))
```

returns:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 4]
```